# Email composer doesn't work on Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send email with email composer cordova plugin. All work well with ios, but on Android i receive the error

> 12    119371   log      Error in Success callbackId:
>   EmailComposer1473338210 : TypeError: undefined is not a function 13
>   119382   error    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function,
>   http://172.31.5.9:8100/cordova.js, Line: 312

with another version of email composer, the "com.jcjee.plugins.emailcomposer 1.4.6" all work well. But with this last version attach file is bugged.

With the cordova email composer on ios i can attach a pdf without any problem, so if it's possibile i want resolve that error.. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `cordova-plugin-email-composer` (0.8.3) has a known bug with Android, and I have yet to find a way to make it work.  0.8.2 will work with Android, but it will not work with iOS.  A workaround I'm using currently (until this issue gets resolved) is a bash script that removes the installed plugin then installs the working version for the given platform that is being built.  Not what I would prefer, but it works and was quick to implement.